# For matrices, under what conditions can we write $AB = BC$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

If $A$ and $B$ are real matrices, when does there exist a matrix $C$ such that $AB = BC$? I understand that there is the case where $A$ and $B$ commute so $AB =BA$, but is there a more general rule (ie. necessary and sufficient conditions)?

Thanks!

Comment: If $ B$ is full rank matrix obviously $C=B^{-1}AB$

Comment: Thanks. That looks like a sufficient condition (which seems obvious in hindsight!). I see why $B$ has to be full rank to be invertible, but why does $A$ have to be full rank as well? If you write it up as an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Are your matrices tall, thin, square, invertible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the OP: do you really think that $AB=BA^T$ when $B$ is symmetric ?

The answer to your question:

find $X\in M_n$ s.t. $A B=BX$ (where $A\in M_m,B\in M_{m,n}$ are given)

can be written, using the Moore Penrose inverse. cf.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse

If $BB^+AB\not= AB$, then no solutions.

If $BB^+AB=AB$, then the solutions are

$X=B^+AB+(I_n-B^+B)W$ where $W$ is an arbitrary $n\times n$ matrix.

Comment: Hello, OP here. Thanks for your answer. I'll have a read up on the Moore Penrose inverse and work through the solution. The answer to the question you asked at the start is no: I made a mistake. Meant to say if $A$ and $B$ commute, then $AB = BA$. Will edit the question to reflect this. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 3):

If $B$ is full rank matrix then we have $C=B^{-1}AB$.
Obviously then $C$ is similar to $A$ with [all consequences of this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity#Properties).

Answer (score 3):

One could interpret the question as: given a matrix $B \in M^{m\times n}$, describe the subspace of $A \in M^{m \times m}$ for which there exists $C \in M^{n \times n}$ such that $AB = BC$.

If $B$ has rank $r$ and $P \in \text{GL}_n$ and $Q \in \text{GL}_m$ are such that $B = P \begin{pmatrix}I_r & 0_{r \times n-r} \\ 0_{m-r \times r} & 0_{m-r \times n-r} \end{pmatrix} Q$, then this is equivalent to
$$P^{-1}AP \begin{pmatrix}I_r & 0_{r \times n-r} \\ 0_{m-r \times r} & 0_{m-r \times n-r} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}I_r & 0_{r \times n-r} \\ 0_{m-r \times r} & 0_{m-r \times n-r} \end{pmatrix} QCQ^{-1} \tag{1}$$
Writing $PAP^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}X_{r \times r} & X_{r \times m-r} \\ X_{m-r \times r} & X_{m-r \times m-r} \end{pmatrix}$ and $QCQ^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}Z_{r \times r} & Z_{r \times n-r} \\ Z_{n-r \times r} & Z_{n-r \times n-r} \end{pmatrix}$, $(1)$ becomes
$$\begin{pmatrix}X_{r \times r} & 0_{r \times n-r} \\ X_{m-r \times r} & 0_{m-r \times n-r} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}Z_{r \times r} & Z_{r \times n-r} \\ 0_{m-r \times r} & 0_{m-r \times n-r} \end{pmatrix}$$
so that $X_{m-r \times r} = 0$, and this is the only restriction.

**Conclusion:** The said subspace of $A \in M^{m \times m}$ is
$$P^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}*_{r \times r} & *_{r \times m-r} \\ 0_{m-r \times r} & *_{m-r \times m-r} \end{pmatrix}P$$
It has dimension $m^2-mr+r^2$.

Comment: dimensions of $P$ and $Q$ are interchanged: $P \in \text{GL}_m$ and $Q \in \text{GL}_n$